# How to get arguments from the Caller of the intercepted method in AspectJ / Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Let's assume that method getSth() from Class Ent can be invoked in class A, class B, class C, class D etc. There are many of them.

Now I need to intercept method getSth() and BEFORE its execution I'd like to use arguments of the method that invoked getSth() and do something with them - I mean do something with values 666 oder 999 (examples below).

I use Spring AOP and AspectJ and I tried with @Around and @Before, with execution and call, but I don't know how can I get these arguments. I would be grateful for help.

**Ent**

```
public class Ent {

    public void getSth() {

        logger.info("Inside Ent.getSth");
    }
}
```

**A**

```
 public class A {

    public void shouldDoSthAndCallMethodGetSth(Integer a) {
        // ...
        Ent ent = new Ent();
    
        ent.getSth();
    }
}
```

**B**

```
 public class B {

    void shouldDoSthAndCallMethodGetSth(Integer b) {
        // ...
        Ent ent = new Ent();
        
        ent.getSth();
    }
}
```

**App**

```
// ...
        A a = new A();
        a.shouldDoSthAndCallMethodGetSth(666);

        B b = new B();
        b.shouldDoSthAndCallMethodGetSth(999);

// ...
```

**AOP**

```
public class GettingSthAdvisor {

@Around("execution(* com.example.demo.aspects.Ent.getSth())")
public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    pjp. ?????????????

    // do something with value 666/999/....

    return pjp.proceed();
}

@Before("call(* com.example.demo.aspects.Ent.getSth())")
public void before(JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
   
  // do something with value 666/999/....
}
```

Comment: Spring AOP can only advise a spring container managed bean. From the code snippets shared all the instances are created with `new` keyword and they are not Spring beans. AspectJ could be the right appraoch.

Comment: I use AspectJ as I said ;) but I don't know how to get arguments' value from the caller method.

Comment: Before I answer your question, I would like to know whether it makes a difference if the callee is called directly or indirectly, i.e. `caller → callee` vs. `caller →  0..n intermediate methods → callee`.

Comment: In my app always caller(argumentWhichLookingFor) -> callee. I mean all intermediate methods must have (argumentWhichLookingFor) in signature anyway so it doesn't matter ;) I'm looking for only one level up method's argument.